# Python script dependent on data file (distutils)

Tags: python, distutils

I have the following directory structure :

```
data __ __init__.py
    |__ file1
    |__ file2
script
README
MANIFEST.in
__init__.py
setup.py
```

The Python script `script` uses the data files in `data`. I am trying to make a source tarball for this script so that it can be used systemwide.

The `__init__.py` file is empty. The file `'script'` invokes the data files through `'data/file1'` and `data/file2`. The contents of `MANIFEST.in` are:

```
include README script
recursive-include data *
```

In `setup.py`, amongst other things, I have :

```
packages = ["data"],
package_data = ["data": "*"],
scripts = ["script"]
```

After setting up the distribution (using `sdist`), I tried installing it on my system. When I try using `script`, it says :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nsoum/anaconda/bin/script", line 54, in <module>
    with open('data/file1', 'r') as do:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/file1'
```

I guess this means that the relative paths of the data-files is not preserved. How do I work around that and make sure that my script has access to the data files ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that `open('data/file1', 'r')` operates relative to the current working directory of the process while the path is really relative to the code file. The best way to get at data files relative to the code distribution is to use `setuptools` rather than bare `distutils` for building and distributing your package. `setuptools` has API for getting at a package's data resource files.